# OpenOffice (3.3) for OS X - save default as .doc/docx

Tags: macos, mac, openoffice-writer

I want OpenOffice to always save Writer documents as doc/docx files. I can do this in Windows, but I can't find out how (by searching or trying) to do it on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to always use OpenOffice format and save a file in .doc when needed. There can be losses of formatting in the transition to .doc.

Comment: Do you have a source for this suggestion?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will keep using the .odt format then.